# Cortex-M4 Interrupt service routines

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-m

Is it neccessary to use to attribute `isr` for an ISR for Cortex-M4 MCU?

```
extern "C" void SysTick_Handler() __attribute__ ((isr));
extern "C" void SysTick_Handler() {                               
}
```

Using the attribute generates some more statements:

```
SysTick_Handler:
mov     r0, sp  @,
bic     r1, r0, #7      @,,
mov     sp, r1  @,
push    {r0}    @
ldr     r0, [sp], #4    @,
mov     sp, r0  @,
bx      lr      @
```

as opposed to omitting the atribute, which generates

```
SysTick_Handler:
bx      lr      @
```

Comment: what compiler/toolchain are you using?

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc (Arch Repository) 13.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The extra code is aligning the stack pointer within the handler.  This would be necessary because the AAPCS requires that the stack pointer is aligned to 8 bytes at any "public interface", e.g. when entering any C function, and so the compiler normally generates code under this assumption.  But an interrupt may at a moment when the mainline code happens to have the stack unaligned, in which case this assumption would not be satisfied.  So the extra "wrapper" instructions align the stack, and allow the code generation for the body of the function to proceed as it normally would, without needing to add more special cases to the compiler.

Of course it happens not to be necessary in this particular case when your handler doesn't actually do anything, but if there were nontrivial code in the handler, it might be important.

So yes, the attribute is necessary.

Comment: Using the attritbute I get the following warning: warning: FP registers might be clobbered despite 'isr' attribute: compile with '-mgeneral-regs-only' [-Wattributes]

Comment: Note, however, that (depending on its configuration), the processor can push padding onto the stack on exception entry in order to align the stack pointer on an 8-byte boundary if necessary, and records the fact for use when the exception returns.  [See Armv7-M Architecture Reference Manual, Section B1.5.7].  So the answer to your question is, "It depends".   Belt and braces can never hurt, however.

Comment: @wimalopaan: So then yes, like it says, you should compile your interrupt handlers with `-mgeneral-regs-only`.  This is another benefit of the `isr` attribute: evidently it enables checks like this.